# Raw html in mvc4 template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates

How to render raw html and prevent escaping in razor template if i am rendering it in this way:

```
var templateService = new TemplateService();
templateService.Parse(templateSource, model, new DynamicViewBag(), templatePath);
```

and templateSource contains:

```
<html>
@MvcHtmlString.Create(this.Model.RenderHead())
<body>
...
```

The problem is that razor escaped all html tags in @MvcHtmlString.Create(this.Model.RenderHead())
And i can't use Html.Raw because there is no HtmlHelper in template context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raw(rawHtml) without 'Html' worked

Answer (score 0):

In a Razor view, you can do something like this:

```
@{ 
  string rawHtml = "<h1>This is raw html</h1>";
  Html.Raw(rawHtml);
 }
```